# Samba not running as AD DC

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller

I am trying to set up my Debian box as an active directory domain controller using Samba 4.5. After going through `samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive` the Samba service does not start and issuing `systemctl start samba` says that samba service is masked and `systemctl unmask samba` does nothing, the service is still masked afterwards.

According to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=837679 then the masking of the Samba service is by design but as I understand it then after provisioning the server as AD DC then that service should be unmasked but it does not happen for me and I am wondering why? And as I understand it then that service needs to be running to run all the other services that are needed so my clients can find the server as a DC and hook up to the domain which they are not doing now.

Here is my smb.conf if that helps

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        netbios name = SERVER
        realm = SERVER.DOMAIN.LAN
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        dns forwarder = 192.168.168.1
        server role = active directory domain controller
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/server.domain.lan/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```

My final aim is to use this server as AD DC, file server and email server but will settle for AD DC to begin with as a starting point :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the service in Samba 4 after provisionning is "samba-ad-dc"

You can try to mask first the old services and start the new one:

```
#systemctl stop smbd nmbd winbind
#systemctl disable smbd nmbd winbind
#systemctl unmask samba-ad-dc
Removed /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service
#systemctl start samba-ad-dc
#systemctl status samba-ad-dc
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this got Samba service up and running, still have problems and will make new questions out of those.